# git and remote security with Encfs

Tags: security, git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i encrypt git on my server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10378/how-do-i-encrypt-git-on-my-server)

I wanted to create a user on my server to use as a private repository. I'd like the files to be encrypted. Encfs will timeout after minutes of inactivity so i was wondering. Is there a way to have git ssh in, run certain commands to mount the encrypted folder, do what it needs then unmount it?

One thought is the password should not be on my server HD so i should either have it locally or a script on my server should create it based on the password i enter when logging in.

Maybe there is a better solution?